# how to check location path every time when navigate to other view/page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've controller to check on home page but it only show one time for the first time.
My question is how to check that every time

```
myApp.controller('routeController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

if($location.path() === '/Home' === true){
    alert("1");
}
}]);
```

then i've controller on body

```
<body  ng-controller="routeController">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "every time", what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: when i click on other link and when i back to home alert is not appearing

Answer (score 1):

try using ng-init:

```
body  ng-controller="routeController" ng-init=initialize()

myApp.controller('routeController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

$scope.initialize = function()
{
if($location.path() === '/Home' === true){
        alert("1");
    }
    }]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check path Whenever you want navigate to other page and also condition based navigation done by using `Config` function and `$routeProvider`.

Hope this will help you.

Add script tag in html page to use route functionality.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/angular-route.js"></script>
```

-

```
myApp = angular.midule('myApp', ['ngRoute']); //Note ngRoute dependency

myApp .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
              templateUrl: "home.html",
              controller: "homeController",
              redirectTo: function (routeParams, path, search) {
                  console.log(routeParams, path, search);

                  if(path === "/")
                  alert("1");
              }         
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also did something like that and is working ok

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    $rootScope.path = $location.path();
    if($location.path() != '/Home'){
        alert("1");
    }
    else{
        alert("2");
    }
});
});
```